# JavaScript how to check if there is text on the page

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I know the code for Python

```py
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://WEBSITE')
assert 'TEXT' in driver.page_source
```

But I need this code in JavaScript.

Comment: I understand you want to check if there is **ANY** text on the page.  If so:
`document.body.innerText!=""`.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the MatchString with whatever you're trying to match.  However, I would recommend searching for specific element(s) and check their text versus the entire body.

```js
var MatchString = "foo";
if(document.body.innerText.indexOf(MatchString) > -1) {
   alert('found');
}
```

```html
<p>
  Test paragraph one
</p>
<p>
  Test paragraph two
</p>
<div>
  Test DIV
</div>
<br/><br/>
<div>
  Test DIV 2 foo
</div>
```

Comment: please write an example

Comment: Excellent, this is just what I was looking for. Thanks, Nathan Champion